# youtube v3 api search fails in Chrome but works in Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, youtube-data-api

Our app Accessible-Youtube has been working fine for many years. Now it only works in Firefox. The current failure point in Chrome is when searching for a video. The code looks like:

```
$.ajax(
      "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=" +
        q +
        "&type=video&videoEmbeddable=true&key=OURKEYISHERE",
      {
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data, status, jqxhr) {
          build(data);
        },
        error: function (data, status, jqxhr) {
          alert("An unknown error occured! Are you connected to the internet?");
        },
      }
    );
```

In Firefox this works fine. In Chrome we get a 403 response with the message

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Requests from referer https://www.cs.unc.edu/ are blocked.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Requests from referer https://www.cs.unc.edu/ are blocked.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

I suspect this must be something about recent changes to the way Chrome handles cookies and/or cross-origin requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Chrome now sends only the domain in the referrer field. Firefox sends the entire path to the page.

I had a full path restriction on the API key. When I changed the restriction to only require the domain it began working again.

This seems like a breaking change in Chrome with respect to their on APIs.